# how to use nghttp2 to send data throught one stream_id on a opened steam before which is still avalable

Tags: c++, alexa-skills-kit, nghttp2

I hava search this forum about nghttp2 about this, temporarily not found anything useful.
I  wrote a demo use nghttp2 to communicate with AVS. 
It's the AVS. 's  Recognizer part. After I eastablished with the AVS. Server, I want to test AVS.'s recognize interface.

So here I found the problem here:
   1. Firstly, I used nghttp2_submit_request() to open a stream (eg. stream_id_x ) with the data_provider set successfully.

2. Sencondly, I used nghttp2_submit_data( ) to send the following data on this steam( eg.stream_id_x ), but it just send the first part message. The other seemed to be ignored.

   And I found the document says "nghttp2_data_source_read_callback" , it has limit at 16kB, and send once if *data_flags to NGHTTP2_DATA_FLAG_EOF. and ignore the following data on the stream( eg.stream_id_x ).  I was a little confuse.

Is anyone met something like this?

Comment: ......well, it looks like  asking question  here  might not get help ...

Comment: 兄弟， 加我QQ 很急， 跟你一起合作nghttp2 Alexa. randy_wales@qq.com

Comment: I am just starting to use nghttp2 so I hope to learn more. Thanks for asking the question. At least there are more of us out there.